# XMLQuery in DB2 for i

Tags: xml, db2-400

I can not find a function similar to ***XMLQuery*** in ***DB2 for i***.

The database supports XML datatype, but there is no XMLQuery function and I can not find a similar one.

Could anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Use xml parse : https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022191.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: XMLPARSE doesn't work as XMLQuery

Let's have the following example:

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (......,
XMLPARSE( DOCUMENT '<product xmlns="http://smpl.org" pid="100-103-99">
      <description>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <price>14.95</price>
        <weight>3 kg</weight>
      </description>
      </product>' PRESERVE WHITESPACE ));
      
 I need a function to extract the value of a XML element.
 
 For instance - how to extract the value 14.95 of the <price> element from the example above?
 There is no XMLQuery in DB2 for i

Comment: you should include your code in the question, not a comment.  Then take a look at the [XMLTABLE function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-xmltable)